# Are numerically indexed PHP arrays initialized contiguously or mapped?

Tags: php, initialization, interpreter

I have a question in regard to PHP arrays.

If I create an array

```
$ids = array();
```

then put something in position 1000 of it:

```
$ids[1000] = 5;
```

How would the interpreter do this internally? Are arrays contiguous lumps of memory like Java? Would it be like int[1000] where 1000 ints are initlialized?

Or is it more of a map where 1000 is the key and it links to the data of 5? I am talking about the internals of PHP.

If I have a large number index, would it be less efficient because it would have to initialize all the indexes? OR is it map based with the number as a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are hashes in PHP. So in your terms, they are mapped. You can check this in your example by looking at `$ids[0...999]` after initialization to see that they don't exist and by comparing `memory_get_usage()` before and after initialization.

Answer (score 2):

All arrays in PHP are effectively associative arrays that maintain insertion order. So:

```
$array[1000] = 5;
```

is fundamentally no different to:

```
$array['hello'] = 'world';
```

Comment: except that the second example won't work because of a typo, yes. :-)